# Running command using XARG

Tags: command-line, sh, xargs

I have example file: test_file

```
//--- Test File--
**RUN_THIS
RUN_THIS00
RUN_THIS01
DONT_RUN00
DONT_RUN00
RUN_THIS02**
```

where `RUN_THIS*` & `DONT_RUN*` are commands.
I would like to run only RUN_THIS commands from test_file without editing the file.
I am looking for option like

```
cat test_file | grep RUN_THIS | xargs  {Some option to be provided to run run_this}
```

I cannot start new shell

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
for cmd in $(grep RUN_THIS < test_file); do
    $cmd --some-option-to-be-provided-to-run-this
done
```

That should work okay as long as there are no spaces in the commands in `test_file`.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval `grep RUN_THIS test_file`
```

Note also the avoidance of a Useless Use of Cat.

Actually, you may have to add a semicolon to the end of each command in `test_file`, or change the `grep` to something which adds the necessary semicolons.

```
eval `awk '/RUN_THIS/ { print; print ";" }'`
```

I'm not sure I understand the requirement to not start a new shell.  Under the hood, the backticks run a subshell, so this might violate that requirement (but then ultimately every external command starts a new process, which starts out as a fork of the current shell process when you run a shell script).  If you are scared of security implications, you should not be using a shell script in the first place, anyhow.

Comment: Oh, and if this is suitable, perhaps you should edit the title, because this is not really about `xargs`.

Comment: `eval` not really recommended.

Answer (score -1):

To run new shells you need to incorparate "ksh" in your command.

In its simplest form

```
RUN_THIS00='ls'
echo $RUN_THIS00 | ksh
```

Comment: The OP said specifically he cannot start a shell.

Comment: Can use exec ofcourse, but are you so sure its "don't want to" start new shell or "cannot" as in not working.

Comment: @triplee Given you have aswered here yourself downgrading someone elses answer just seems wrong especially since you have assumed things on questions behalf...a reconsider is in order.

Comment: My other quib with your answer was with the Useless Use of `ksh` Where Plain Ole `sh` Would Do Just Fine.  I have submitted an edited version of your question; if it gets approved, I can and will change my vote.  Sorry if I was breaking the etiquette here; I googled for a bit but could not come up with an authoritative recommendation against down-voting "competing" answers; but I certainly ought to have left a comment explaining this.

Comment: Looks like my edit wasn't accepted. Anyway, it basically amounted to `grep RUN_THIS test_file | sh`.  Maybe you want to edit your reply yourself.